# How to check charged percentage of battery and to adjust its thresholds?

Tags: 10.10, battery

1. I was wondering how to check the current charged percentage of
   battery on my Lenovo T400?
2. I forgot which program I used to control the battery to stop
   charging at 60% and start charging at 40%.

   Now I want to adjust the thresholds. So I wonder how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1: In general, the directory `/proc/acpi/battery/` should have a host of information about your battery. So `cat /proc/acpi/battery/info` should bring up original manufacturing information and `cat /proc/acpi/battery/state` should bring up current information, including the charging status.

More specifically, since you have a Lenovo, I think these commands might work as well (maybe these will work and the above ones won't):

```
cat /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/state
cat /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_percent
cat /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_running_time
cat /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_charging_time
cat /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_capacity
```

2: I *think* this is what you're after:

Set starting charge at 40%:

`echo 40 > /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh`

Set stopping charge at 70%:

`echo 70 > /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh`

Display charging thresholds:

`cat /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/*_charge_thresh`

[There's a whole host more features, commands and information here.](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi)

Comment: Thanks! My system does not have directory `smapi` under /sys/devices/platform/smapi. It does not have the files supposed to be under `smapi`, such as `remaining_percent`, `remaining_charging_time`, `start_charge_thresh`.

Comment: And I take it you don't have `/proc/acpi/battery` as well?

Comment: I have `/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/ `. But I cannot find in the three files `alarm`, `info` and `state`  the information about how much percentage has been charged.

Comment: Is there anything in the `/BAT0` directory?

Comment: There are three files `alarm`, `info` and `state`.

Comment: Thanks! I finally get those directories and files you mentioned. But the battery charge does not change after I set the new thresholds. How shall I do?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. It looks like there's [a bug](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#T60p_writing_to_start_charge_thresh.2Fstop_charge_thresh_does_not_work.21) related to that.